# How to concatenate a php variable in an echo statement with a javascript onClick event?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing an application where each user has a uid and that uid is a folder. I have changed the name of the current directory to the uid and this displays the proper files on a dropdown of the files in the folder that is on the page but then the location still goes to the parent folder and not the the uid folder. How do I concatenate the uid variable with the location so it is going to the right folder? Here is what I have so far

```
<?php
chdir("$uid");

echo "<select name='menu'>";
$files = array_filter(scandir($dir), function($item) {
return $item[0] !== '.';
});
foreach (glob("*.php") as $file){
if ($file != 'new.php' && $file !='config.php'){
    echo "<option value='$file'>".basename($file,".php"). "</option>";
}
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='button' onClick='location=this.form.menu.options[this.form.menu.selectedIndex].value;' 
value='GO'>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

I have tried doing this:

```
 echo "<input type='button' onClick='location='$uid/'.this.form.menu.options[this.form.menu.selectedIndex].value;' 
value='GO'>";
```

But then I run into syntax errors. Is there a way I can concatenate the uid with the location file name?

Comment: HTML attributes, e.g. `onClick`, must have their values enclosed within double quotes, e.g. `onClick="your_code_goes_here"`. Your `onClick` is likely failing because you never added that in. Be sure to enclose the `onClick` JavaScript in double quotes, remembering to escape those quotes i.e. do `onClick=\"your_code_goes_here\"`. Other problems may or may not exist, but this one would definitely cause a major syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate string in js with "+" operator, while in php you should use "."

So you can try this: (i didn't test it)

```
echo '<input type="button" onClick="location=\''.$uid.'/\'+this.form.menu.options[this.form.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">';
```